# gridview image border

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am using gridview for displaying group of images from xml using xml parsing, now I want to display the border around each image in gridview. All images should display outline border on image in gridview .how to set border for each image in gridview?

Comment: why don't you set the background in the xml of the grid item.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting a resource/color to the imageview's a background on the grid and also specify a padding for for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial:

http://www.firstdroid.com/2011/02/06/android-tutorial-gridview-with-icon-and-text/

In the grid.item.xml, and add a background:

If the image size is fixed, add a .png transparent background with border.
If the image changes size, you need to use a 9-layer image.

BR, 
Adrian.

Answer (score 0):

I used this layout in my project you can use this hope it helps.

```
//Border drawable xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
      <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
      <stroke android:width="0.7dip" android:color="#808080"/>
    </shape>


//Layout xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/grid_selector"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="3dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/grid_image"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/gridview_image_desc"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grid_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:textColor="#808080"
            android:textSize="13sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grid_text2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
```